# How to sort an associative array by a part of a value php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting

I have an array:

```
array:1 [▼
  "Ice Coffee" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "4,78"
    1 => "7,57"
    2 => "12,61"
    3 => "2,89"
  ]
]
```

I need to sort it on the value behind the comma, is this possible?

57 -> 61 -> 78 -> 89

So the outcome will be:

```
array:1 [▼
  "Ice Coffee" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "7,57"
    1 => "12,61"
    2 => "4,78"
    3 => "2,89"
  ]
]
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: usort wil help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a custom sort function, like:

```
<?php
$array = [0 => "4,78", 1 => "7,57", 2 => "12,61", 3 => "2,89"];

function order_behind_comma($a, $b) {
    $_a = explode(",", $a); $_a = intval($_a[1]);
    $_b = explode(",", $b); $_b = intval($_b[1]);

    if($_a == $_b) return 0;
    return ($_a < $_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'order_behind_comma');
print_r($array);
```

This will return:

```
Array ( [1] => 7,57 [2] => 12,61 [0] => 4,78 [3] => 2,89 )
```

If you have a multidimensional array you can loop through all categories like "Ice Coffee" and run the uasort for each category.

Answer (score 1):

uasort can deal with this kind of problem like this :

```
$test = [
"Ice Coffee" => [
        0 => "4,78",
        1 => "7,57",
        2 => "12,61",
        3 => "2,89"
    ]
];
uasort($test['Ice Coffee'], 'test');
function test($a, $b)
{
    if(explode(',', $a)[1] == explode(',', $b)[1])
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return (explode(',', $a)[1] < explode(',', $b)[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

but the explode inside the function is surely not the better to do it.

more information about uasort here :[uasort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uasort.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
usort($array, function ($item1, $item2) {
list($first,$first1) = split(',',$item1);
list($second,$second1) = split(',',$item2);
if ($first == $second) return 0;
return $first < $second ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = ["7,57", "12,61", "4,78", "2,89"];

usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = explode(',', $a)[1];
    $b = explode(',', $b)[1];

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($array);

// Array ( [0] => 7,57 [1] => 12,61 [2] => 4,78 [3] => 2,89 )
```